# XDMP-BADNCNAME: :link error in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, xbrl

Error snippet i get when using the Query console of MarkLogic

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-BADNCNAME: :link
>
> Stack Trace
>
> At line 1 column 18: In xdmp:eval("declare namespace
>   xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/link...", (), 11967107844575880929...)
>
> 1. declare namespace xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase";
> 2. declare namespace xmlns:bd-alg="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-algemeen";
> 3. declare namespace xmlns:bd-bedr="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedrijven";

Anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: using MarkLogic Query Console to test if i can use it to handle XBRL documents. I tried declaring all the namescpaces used inside the XML/XBRL file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace declarations must bind a namespace to a prefix that must be the NCName, without the `xmlns:` part, like so:

```
declare namespace link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase";
declare namespace bd-alg="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-algemeen";
declare namespace bd-bedr="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt11/bd/20161207/dictionary/bd-bedrijven";
```

There was probably a confusion with the XML syntax to bind namespaces, which uses the `xmlns:` prefix to distinguish bindings from regular attributes:

```
<link:calculationLink xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase">
  ...
</link:calculationLink>
```

In XQuery, this is not needed because the `declare namespace` syntax already makes it clear that these are prefixes.